# Can Ubuntu 18.04 be fixed without reinstalling

Tags: dual-boot

I have win 7 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.  It went well and I used it for most of the day.  Then I rebooted and chose win7.  It did come up but it couldn't access anything.  Like the explorer would not come up and it couldn't run any programs.
I re-installed it and now it comes up but Ubuntu doesn't.
So, I thought I'd go through the Ubuntu install and see if there was an option to "fix", but all it comes up with is to remove that and re-install over it.
Isn't there some way to do this without a complete re-install?  (I was so proud to have gotten my Thunderbird contents moved to Ubuntu, I'd hate to have to do that again).
Thanks

Comment: Did you have free space on computer to install ubuntu on, or did you have to shrink Win 7 with ubuntu installer?

Comment: I tried a few of them.  But that question is a different situation.  I have a dual boot on the same drive, not an external drive.  There should be a way to get Ubuntu to repair itself without a full reinstall.  Or do I just have to keep installing windows and then Ubuntu until they both work?

Comment: Oh, I probably had enough but I did add some more just in case.  Maybe that was it.  There should have been plenty of space for the amount I added.  Good question though.  Maybe now that I have set the space aside I should just install both again.  I eventually want to remove the windows.  Maybe I should just bite the bullet and forget windows right now.